# UITableView in Today extension unresponsive

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

My `Today extension` is editable, so the user can change what is visible in the widget. The problem I am having is that usually after adding adding new elements to the `widget`, the widget becomes unresponsive. To make it work again I have to close the notification center and re-open it.

The data is correctly added to the `tableview` and it updates just fine. 
After the user has made a change to the widgets via the containing app, I send an update request using `MMWormHole` and it arrives to the `widget`. Then I call this code:

```
[self.wormHole listenForMessageWithIdentifier:@"updateSceneWidget" listener:^(id  _Nullable messageObject) {
  [[WidgetManager getInstance]updateWidgetsData];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
  [self setPreferredContentSize:self.tableView.contentSize];
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, this seems to have something to do with the device being debugged. When it is run normally it doesn't seem to be a problem at all.